# Google chrome not working in ubuntu14.04 server (Karma)

Tags: google-chrome, karma-runner, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

I trying to run the TEST $ ./scripts/test.sh
but I am getting

```
Starting Karma Server (http://karma-runner.github.io)
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://xx.xx.xx:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome`enter code here`
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
```

Please help to fix it.
Please refer screenshot also

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZI8L.png]

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be that you are logged in to your server via SSH with no window GUI, possible Chrome can not start without that.

- login to your Ubuntu with graphical user interface
- or try PhantomJS instead of Chrome